# Que significa el operador ^ en lenguaje de programación como JavaScript y python?

Tags: javascript, python, algoritmos

He visto que hay una forma de cambiar el valor de dos variables y es con el operador ^, pero en si no se que significa
Ejemplo

```
let a=2;
let b=3;

a^=b;
b^=a;
a^=b;

console.log(a) //3
console.log(b) //2
```

Comment: En este caso es un XOR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este operador realiza una operacion XOR en binario bit a bit

Supongamos **a = 2**,  **b = 3** en binario seria **a = 10**, **b = 11**

Entonces

> a ^ b = 10 XOR 11 = 01

El resultado en decimal seria igual a **1**

Otros ejemplos

> 3 **^** 5 = 011 **XOR** 101 = 110 → 6

> 12 **^** 7 = 1100 **XOR** 0111= 1011 → 11

Comprueba la tabla de la compuerta XOR si lo necesitas

[image: Tabla de la operacion XOR]